# USB tethering in windows stopped functioning

Tags: ip, internet-connection

I have a laptop with windows 7 os in it. I used to connect internet in my laptop  using my android phone (via USB tethering). Yesterday, I tried setting static IP to my machine in the network connection properties. It didn't workout and I just enabled dhcp again(if I set static IP I wasn't able to connect to internet from the machine. So I undid all the Changes and enabled dhcp).

Now, whenever I connect my phone and enable tethering options there are two network connection's being shown and I couldn't access internet from my laptop. Both network connection's have no internet access text along with their names. Also I feel that, one network connection's name changes after reboot every time(I am not sure when the connection's name changes but I am sure the network connection name is being changed as I noticed it twice after reboot)

I am writing this from my phone as I couldn't connect to internet via my laptop.  Any help would be great!! Sorry for the typo's

Comment: Try another Android phone on that computer, or try your phone on another computer. This will exclude 50% of the possible fault.

Comment: Delete that network connection, and ANY connection that your phone might have been using, reboot, and then try to connect again.  There's a section in the registry that keeps all the parameters for each of your connections, and you will need to destroy the one that it is remembering and messing you up,   (I wouldn't necessarily mess with the registry part of my answer.)

Comment: @DaaBoss You mean disabling the network connection?? I don't see an option to delete the connection

Comment: @davidbaumann I tried tethering my phone with another PC and I was able to connect with internet. Also I used a different phone with my laptop and my laptop was able to connect to internet. The problem occurs only when I use my phone's USB tethering with my laptop. May be I messed something in the connection that is particularly setup for my phone(I undid whatever changes I did yesterday. Don't know why this is happening with my phone only).

Comment: No, I didn't mean "disabling" that network connection.  I do mean that, even if you can't see it except through the registry, you can delete ALL the settings, but ONLY for that specific "USB network connection to my phone(4)".  (The "4" refers to the fact that the registry OFTEN has more than one config for a connection, and it may or may not display the "4" to you.  Still, deleting the corrupt one can force it to create one that works. -- I've done it!)